# Prove polynomial $n^6-n^5+n^4+n^2-n+1$ is positive for each natural number $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that the polynomial
$$p(x)=n^6-n^5+n^4+n^2-n+1$$
is positive for every natural number $n$.
I have tried factoring it and got $$(n^4+1)(n^2-n)=(n^4+1)n(n-1),$$ but couldn't get anything else out of it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: actual factors are $(n^4+1)(n^2-n+1) $  while the second factor is positve, check discrimninant

Comment: Please make subjects informative about the mathematical content. “How do I prove this?”, “Can someone help me here?” “It this right?”, etc. are bad titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
n^6-n^5+n^4+n^2-n+1 &= n^5(n-1) + n^4 + n(n-1) + 1\\
&= n(n^4+1)(n-1)+n^4+1\\
&\ge n^4+1\\&>0
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

correct is
$$  (n^4+1)(n^2 - n + 1)  = (n^2 - n \sqrt 2 + 1)(n^2 + n \sqrt 2 + 1)(n^2 - n + 1)$$

all three quadratic factors are positive, check discriminants

the factors of the quartic come from Sophie Germain's identity
$$ a^4 + 4 b^4 = (a^2 +2ab + 2 b^2)  (a^2 -2ab + 2 b^2) $$
with, I guess, $a=n, b = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Not sure why this is  associated with Germain

Comment: There was no need of factoring $n^4+1$ as it is already positive ($\geq 1$) for all real $n$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes. The only purpose in answering, really,  is that this OP seems not to be able to factor correctly. If you look in the question, the $1$ has disappeared.

Comment: Ok got it. +1 and I wasn't aware that the identity is named on Sophie Germain. It was part of high school factoring techniques.

Answer (score 0):

$n^6-n^5-n+1+n^4+n^2 = (n^5-1)(n-1)= (n-1)^2(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)+n^4+n^2 \ge n^4+n^2\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’d be solving for n in the inequality $n^6 + n^4 + n^2 + 1 > n^5 + n$.  For $n > 1, n^6 > n^5$ and for all $n, n^4 + n^2 + 1 > n$, so the inequality must be true for all $n$. I don’t think factorising will help you prove it.